# Crystal report - displaying details and report header in a same row

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5

[image: screenshot]

I have a requirement in crystal report, where we have to show details section and report header together, so data will be displayed in a same row and according to the input the detail section can also grow in both direction row wise and column wise. Please use the sample picture for reference.

Is there any way to keep them together like in HTML where we can divide any table into one or more columns?

Any kind of information would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In crystal it is not possible to add detail section in report header part..

How ever you can split detail section to multiple layout!!

1 - Right click report body then select Section Expert.

2 - Select multiple column.

3 - Then on layout you can provide detail size and gap detail.

Also you can insert multiple detail section and can swap inside the detail section.  **but not in report header part**

Comment: Hello ankur, can I change the behaviour of data population inside detail section, I mean instead of populating data horizontally or row wise, can I do it column wise

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for this purpose you need to use sub reports.

create a sub report and place in header section. Now  limit the width of the sub report to the extent you need.

In sub report place the fields in details and supress rest all sections.

Now you can see header and details in report header..

Can you share along with sub report what you want to view in header?

Comment: Thank you Siva, I tried by creating subreport, and including fields in details, but I need to populate the detail field in the header section, vertical way, not row wise!! Row wise no issue it is working..

Comment: Can you show a picture of how it is now and how do you want to view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-report or setting up the section expert option.

> Go to section expert

- step 1: Suppress page header
- step 2: At report header mark ***Underlay Following Section***

> [Section Expert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d31bz.jpg)